# Facebook Ads Api Request fails with #273 requires user to be admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to query the Facebook Ads API with the Graph Api Explorer. I have two Ads Account connected to me (if i query `/me/adaccounts/` I see both) one is my own and the other one I'm only admin on but not owner.

The Problem is with the one I'm not the owner. If I query my Adaccount with `/act_<ACT_ID/stats` I get a normal response with the stats back if I query the other account i get:

> (#273) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the ad account. User `<MY_USER_ID>` not admin on ad account `<ACT_ID>`.",

I can see both Adaccounts normal in the Facebook Adsmanager.

What I have done to get the response is:

- Create an Facebook App
- Added the Adaccount under developer.facebook.com -> myApp -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account
- open GraphExplorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
- select my created App
- get AccessToken (ads_management, ads_read)
- go to url `me/adaccounts/`
- if i click on my adaccount it works if i click on the other i get the #273 error

I don't see what I'm doing wrong if someone could point me in the right direction I would be gratefull.

Comment: Have you added both your ad accounts to your App?

Comment: I've yet to see this error be inaccurate, are you sure you're the admin of both the ad account and the app, and aren't just an advertiser or have some other role on the ad account?

Comment: I'm not Administrator on the Account were I'm getting the error. I have permissions: 2,3,4,7 role: 1002. But i would think that with these permissions i could read in the account as i can in the Adsmanager

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to your ad account is inactive or in a bad standing. Additionally if your access level of your ad account is in development level these types of errors may occur. please go through what's mentioned on the doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access)
If you upgrade your account to basic or standard access levels this will be solved.

On development access level only end to end workflows are suggested. The following text is extracted from facebook documentation.

> The development access level is designed for development purposes and is ideal for people who are just starting to build out their tool. In this level, you would not yet have customers using your tool. This level is open to all developers, and is intended to build out end-to-end workflows on the API before you get full permissions.

A similar issue has been reported on facebook bug reports. you can see the thread [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1706025782961941/)

Answer (score 0):

*As [@Igy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21062/igy) stated it in a comment:* "a user has to be the admin of both the ad account and the app (and not just an advertiser or have some other role on the ad account)".

There is 2 places to check that:

- the app's roles page, https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/roles/
- the account's peoples page, https://business.facebook.com/settings/people/

Once the user is admin on both side, the API calls will be just fine.

Comment: I had to also add “Authorized Ad Account IDs” in `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APP_ID}/settings/advanced/`

Answer (score -3):

Your business manager doesn't have admin rights. Please check the admin rights of the business manager and also add the app in your business manager to get the report stat(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/business-manager#update-business).

Comment: This is not related to the OP's problem